# Cannot redirect to user_panel page after login ... header() not working

Tags: php

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysqli_connect_error()); 
        $db=mysqli_select_db($con,"users") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysqli_connect_error());
        $count=0;
        $username = $_POST['username']; 
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE Username= '$_POST[username]' && Password= '$_POST[password]'";
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
        if($count>0){
            session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header ("Location: user_panel.php");
        }
        else{
            echo "Incorret username or password ...";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you are getting any error

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: verify that user_panel file actually exists and on your server

Comment: Add an exit() after your header call too or the script continues to execute and you don't need it to after a header call

Answer (score 0):

use fullpath in header location like this

```
<?php
$baseurl = "http://examplesite.com/";

header("location: ".$baseurl."user_panel.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by javascript also.

```
window.location.href='user_panel.php';
```